# Reactjs Router version4 Routing issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using react-router version 4,as routing configuration for the component is done,but the component is not mounted as I tried with componentDidMount() method,the console log is not shown.

Here is my code,

```
import { Route,Switch,hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import {HashRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import { createHistory, useBeforeUnload } from 'history';

 <Router history={hashHistory}>
      <div>
          <Route exact path='/userlogin/' component={LoginPage}></Route>  
          <Route exact path='/dashboard/' component={Dashboard}></Route> 
          <Route exact path='/forgotpassword/' component={ForgotPasswordPage}></Route>
      </div>
 </Router>
```

As the page is coming empty when i tried with router url path of component.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.!

Comment: what url are you trying?

Comment: I tried with the url of routepath in local.For eg: Login page  url i tried with /userlogin/  as mentioned in router path configuration.

Comment: have you tried removing "exact"?

Comment: What about deleting that trailing slash in your path attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My routes look like this:

```
var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={Main}>
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path='chapters' component={ChapterListContainer} />
            <Route path='chapters/chapter:id' component={ChapterPageContainer}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
);
```

There are a couple of differences:

1. there is no `<div>` around the routes, they are encapsulated with a
   `path='/'` to indicate the root component
2. I have an index route also which tells the router which component should be shown by default

Comment: but I'm pretty sure the `<div>`should not be there

Comment: nothing wrong with the `<div>` as well :-) See here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: one thing I notice however is that you are using hashHistory... first I wonder if `history={hashHistory}` is necessary, second, would not the url be #userlogin or something similar?

Comment: my thoughts go in this direction as well